# By how many orders of magnitude does 345,632 differ from 567,123,423?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If you convert each number to scientific notation and round off the mantissa then you end up with $10^5$ and $10^9$.

Therefore these number differ by 4 orders of magnitude.

But $\frac{567,123,423}{345,632}=1,640.83(2dp)$

This number in scientific notation is $1.6*10^3$ which when rounded is $10^3$. Three orders of magnitude.

I would have thought that these two methods should give the same result. 
Is the first method just a quick estimate method or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you round the 5 up to ten you are giving yourself a different order of magnitude. Don't round the 5 and you'll get the same result.